# How to read JSON file data using typescript

Tags: javascript, html, json, typescript

I am developing simple web application to view all projects and search project by name. for that I have created class diagram something like this. for the backend I am using Typescript/JS and for the frontend I am using html.

I want to do these senarios :

1. Show all project when we open the browser.
2. have search textbox in the browser. so If I type anything in there I want to filter data from JSON file.

This is my JSON file

```
{
  "projects": [
    { "id": 1, "name" : "Project 1" },
    { "id": 2, "name" :"Command 2" },
    { "id": 3, "name" :"Project 3" },
    { "id": 4, "name" :"Project 4" },
  ]
}
```

I have created simple class diagram for that:

[image]

After that I have created some class but I am not sure are these correct or not.

```
class Project {
   private id?: number;
   private name?: string;
}

class ProjectFactory {

    getAllProjects(){
    }

    searchProject(){

    }
}
```

// JSON file need to add in project.JSON file`

### HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="product.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Embla - Product Management Software</a>
                    <img src="/images/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                </div>
            </nav>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    
            <table class="table" id="myTable">
                <thead class="table-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width:50%;">Id</th>
                    <th style="width:50%;">Project Name</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Project 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Command 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Project 3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>Project 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here I just want to verify how to write typescript class correctly for this above mention senario. and how to connect Typesecript/JS file to html and also how to featch data from JSON file to Typescript class using get methods.

here also I added sample codes. but I want to know how to get from JSON file and show in view. and for the search also.

```
class Project {
  id!:number;
  name!:string;
 
  constructor(id:number, name:string) {
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
  }
 
  
} 

class ProjectFactory {
  // Example of method
  getName() : string {
    let p = new Project(1, "A");
    return p.id + " "+ p.name
  }
}

let project = new ProjectFactory(); 

console.log(project.getName());
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break your question into parts.

1. [JavaScript/Typescript to add a new HTML element to the DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp). You can call this, passing in your new `"id"` and `"name"`
2. Assuming your JSON is hosted on the server, [use fetch requests in Typescript to get the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This might look something like:

```js
const rawData: any = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => response.json());
rawData.foreach(//inject your new HTML);
```

This code is rough, and it would be helpful to define what type your JSON is instead of `'any'`. Hope this provides a good start